# Matcher for strictly all elements of a list

Tags: java, junit, pattern-matching

I want to test the result of a java method that returns a Set of elements and I need to check if the result contains exactly all the elements but not necessarily in the same order.

I'm using junit `assertThat` for the test but I don't know the matcher to use.

Basically I'm looking for something like `JUnitMatchers.hasItem(T ... elements)` that fails if at least one of the element returned by the method is not in elements. And since my method returns a set, it would be nice that the matcher fails if `elements` contains twice the same element.

Does anyone knows such a matcher?

Comment: If it's a Set, it _can't_ contain the same element twice...

Comment: You may be able to just use `Set.equals()`, although it may not give as much failure info as a specific Set matcher.

Comment: Sorry, I think didn't make myself clear enough. I'm talking of the elements given to the Matcher since it's usually a table of elements so it is technically possible to call AssertThat(myMethod(), matcher(e1, e2, e1)) but in this case the test must fails even if method returns a set {e1, e2}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Hamcrest 1.2.1. It has an [IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/browse/trunk/hamcrest-java/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.java) matcher, which perfectly fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the collection that the method returns. You might have to convert it to a `List` for that. Then use standard `equals` to check if it's the same as a sorted expected collection.